# Executing pdftk with php exec on Ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: php

```
exec("cd /var/www && PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/ pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf 4.pdf output final.pdf");
```

I'm trying to execute this command on Ubuntu 12.04.3, it's working fine when I'm connecting via ssh, but it doesn't work when I'm executing it with PHP giving "Unable to fork the current command", any idea what to do?